# How to debug (gdb) a binary that is invoked with xvfb-run?

Tags: linux, gdb, xvfb

I have a binary that I usually run as follows:

```
$ xvfb-run ./bin --param1 foo
```

However, now that I need to debug it using GDB, I'm not able to do:

```
$ gdb --args xvfb-run ./bin --param1 foo
```

because `"/usr/bin/xvfb-run": not in executable format: file format not recognized.`

Is there a way to do this? For example, by using **Xvfb**?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xvfb-run` is a shell script! Hence, when you want to run all of xvfb-run it in `gdb`, you'd

```bash
gdb --args sh $(which xvfb-run) ./bin --param1 foo
```

But that's probably not what you want! Doesn't sound to me like you're interested in debugging the `Xvfb` X server itself. More like you're interested in debugging `./bin`. You would rather

```bash
xvfb-run gdbserver localhost:9999 ./bin --param1 foo
```

Which starts a gdbserver with your program `./bin` loaded, and you can then attach to it with gdb

```bash
$ gdb ./bin
(gdb) target remote localhost:9999
(gdb) run
```